# Add div on hover using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I build a project something like "trip planner" but I need to add on my cloned div-object an verticl line on left border with css:

```
.line
  { width:5px, height:200px; background:red;}
```

so to be something [like this](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/04/timeline-portfolio/) (you can see on hover an vertical line)

I was try to do this with code:

```
$(function() {
    //$( ".draggable" ).resizable();
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
      revert: 'invalid', 
      helper:"clone",
      snap: "#drop_here td", 
      opacity: 0.7
    });
    $( "#drop_here td" ).droppable({
      // accept only from left div, 
      // this is necessary  to prevent clones duplicating inside droppable
      accept: '#left .draggable',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        // 4 append clone to droppable
        $( this ).append(
          // 1 clone draggable helper
          $(ui.helper).clone()

          // 2 make the clone draggable
          .draggable({
             containment:"#table",
            snap: "#drop_here td" 
          })
          // 3 make the clone resizable
          .resizable());

//HERE IS MY PROBLEM IN CODE
        $(".draggable").hover(function() {
    $(this).append("<div class='line'></div>");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("line");
});
      }
    });
  });
```

but dont work!

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/erofot/138)

Comment: dude it's working..inspect the code..

Comment: no, the vertical line on hover won't to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that your `css` has a `,` insted of a `;`

```
.line { 
  display: none;
  width: 5px; 
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

Then for the `jquery` modify like this:

```
$('.draggable').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.line').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.line').hide();
});
```

In your markup place a `.line` (only **one**) just `after` every `.draggable`, but not on `hover` or it will `append` it every time you `hover` the `.draggable` creating tons of `.line`s

JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/steo/JB7jN/1/

Comment: very clean solution :)

Comment: but I need it only for cloned object... again is the same

Comment: dude, you're missing to add .line to draggable, I made it in the one I linked and it worked perfectly. http://jsbin.com/erofot/157 look this code

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind the .hover() in the document ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".draggable").hover(function() {
          $(this).append("<div class='line'></div>");
      }, function() {
          $(this).children('.line').remove();
      });
});
```

Comment: steo's answer is not realy correct.. it will show and hide all elements with the class 'line'.. but there are none in the first place.. I just copied your code but in the mouseout handler you should not just remove the class of the line element, use $(this).children('.line').remove(); instead. I updated my first post for you.

Comment: No, you're way is incorrect: you will every time create a line div which is a bad way, I'll fix my code.

Comment: you can easyly create dom elements on hover as long as you remove them on mouseout.

Comment: No its not bad.. its a fine solution, there is no problem with creating and removing dom elements. Thats what javascript is for.. dom manipulation.

Comment: It's a bad way when you don't need to. Just my two cents.

Comment: It could be more efficient, cause the elements should be always there in this example, i agree.

Comment: Well i agree with @MarkRijsmus this piece of code does work when we just want to add a div and remove on mouseout. +1

Answer (score 0):

Your "hover out" handler removes the class from $(this) -- not from the appended child.

It's probably bad practice to dynamically create elements on hover, that are never deleted & will presumably gradually fill the document with garbage.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to add the line to the clone add the start property to the draggable options like this:

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
  revert: 'invalid', 
  helper:"clone",
  snap: "#drop_here td", 
  opacity: 0.7,
  start: function(event, ui){
    var clone = $(ui.helper);
    if (clone.children('div.line').length == 0)
        clone.append("<div class='line'></div>");
  }
});
```

Tested this and it works like a charm.. Dont forget to remove this part:

```
    $(".draggable").hover(function() {
         $(this).append("<div class='line'></div>");
    }, function() {
         $(this).removeClass("line");
    });
```

Comment: Ok well it is here.. I saved it as template now.. or what else should i do? I'm not realy known to jsbin..

Comment: just go on BINS and then CLONE and after that copy the link nad paste here

Comment: I dont know.. the element is there.. and only in the clone.. pls mark as answer.. something might be wrong with your css.. or maybe try to put '&nbsp;' (non breaking space) in the div

Comment: ok ok, I will mark the answer but please send me if you can this code on email: mslavko6@gmail.com ...

Comment: go on BINS / DOWNLOAD and send to email mslavko6@gmail.com

Comment: don't work, I will chose your andswer with css code, the probbaly best solution, THANKS FOR HELP